# Web scraping a website when page source doesn't contain what I see on browser

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Suppose I want to scrape the data (marathon running time) in this website: https://www.valenciaciudaddelrunning.com/en/marathon/2021-marathon-ranking/

One Google chrome when I right-click and select 'Inspect' or 'View page source', I don't see the actual data embedded in the source page (e.g. I can see the name of athlete, the split times, etc on the browser, but the source code doesn't contain any of those). I have tried web-scraping other websites where the data I need are embedded inside those   tab, and using `requests` and `bs4` packages in Python I manage to extract the data I want from the websites. For the Valencia marathon URL posted above, is it possible to do web scraping, and if so how?

From some quick google search it looks like some webpages are dynamically loaded with Javascript (correct me if I'm wrong). Is that the case if the website appears to be interactive or if I don't see the browser output when I inspect the source code? Is package like `selenium` useful for the the above Valencia marathon URL? I know basically nothing about how websites are rendered so if someone can direct me to some useful resources that would be great.

**Update**: so apparently the URL provided above is not the actual website containing the data as they are in an `<iframe>`. This URL should be closer to the actual source of the data:
https://resultados.valenciaciudaddelrunning.com/en/2021/maraton-clasificados.php?y=2021
But it looks like the leaderboard page, and the result for each athlete when I click on their names, still don't show the actual data when I inspect the source.

Comment: Web scraping is an exercise in reverse-engineering.  When navigating the page manually, your browser's development/debugging tools can help you find additional requests being made in the background for data (AJAX requests), and potentially to debug the code on the page and find where specific data is coming from and how it's being used.  Alternatively, a tool like Selenium can be used as a kind of in-memory "headless browser", which internally provides a complete engine for HTML/CSS/JavaScript.  You could use that to automatically process the page's JavaScript and update its DOM.

Answer (score 1):

There's `<iframe>` in the page, so data you see in the browser is loaded from different URL:

```py
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://resultados.valenciaciudaddelrunning.com/en/2021/maraton.php?y=2021"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

table = soup.select_one("#tabPodium")

df = pd.read_html(StringIO(str(table)))[0]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Unnamed: 0                Name Official time Country
0           1   CHERONO, LAWRENCE       2:05:12     KEN
1           2         DESO, CHALU       2:05:16     ETH
2           3  KACHERAN, PHILEMON       2:05:19     KEN
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally:

- Be sure that the data you want to extract are not in an **iframe**, in such a case try to crawl the page URL of the iframe and not the URL of the page that includes it.
- In your settings of your browser you can disable the JavaScript in order to easily find out if the data reach out to you in a transitional server side way or is downloaded in a dynamic JavaScript way. If such a case, the easy way is to go at the network tab of the browser and try to find out the **Fetch/XHR** request that has the data you may interested about.

In your question the information you need is in an iframe so you need to crawl that instead.